# What is the use of the script mentioned?

Tags: meanjs

working on the sample meanjs application. I am not able to understand the below code snippet. 
Kindly explain the use of this script in  layout.server.view.html view.

```
<!--Embedding The User Object-->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var user = {{ user | json | safe }};
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `user` is being sent via express/swig everytime a request is made to the route `/*` (see [here](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/core/server/routes/core.server.routes.js#L14)) so that user data can be used by AngularJS.

If you check the file `core.server.controller.js` ([here](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/core/server/controllers/core.server.controller.js)), you will see that MEAN.JS passes a user object in the response in this code block:

```
res.render('modules/core/server/views/index', {
    user: safeUserObject
});
```

Then in the code block you mentioned, you're assigning user object sent by express/swig to the variable `user` which can then be accessed later using `$window.user` similarly to what is done [here](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/users/client/services/authentication.client.service.js#L12).

[**`json`**](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/#json) and [**`safe`**](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/#safe) are two swig filters. The first one returns a string representation of a JavaScript object and the second one forces the input to not be auto-escaped.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it nicely.  I understand your point. Just want to ask is this the only way to pass the user object from express/swig to angular? Could there be other approaches for doing this same thing.

Comment: That really depends on the technologies you're using. This seems to be a good solution for a MEAN app. There might be other ways, but the principle is the same I think.