# Who embeds the user object in MEAN js HTML file?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

There is a user object in MEAN js HTML source.

`var user = {{ user | json | safe }};`

see line 58 on https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/v0.3.3/app/views/layout.server.view.html

When the page is loaded, and I view source, I can see the user object loaded.

So does the server load it based on the cookie sent in the request, or does the angular app handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being sent via express with the help of the templating engine. With the AngularJS service defined in this [file](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/v0.3.3/public/modules/users/services/authentication.client.service.js) you are able to access the auth data and use it throughout the app.

A few months ago I answered a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519300/what-is-the-use-of-the-script-mentioned/37523699#37523699) for a more recent version of MEAN.js but will indeed help you for this case.